# Pandas - contains from other DF

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I have 2 dataframes:

DF A:

[image]

and DF B:

[image]

I need to check every row in the DFA['item'] if it contains some of the values in the DFB['original'] and if it does, then add new column in DFA['my'] that would correspond to the value in DFB['my'].

So here is the result I need:

[image]

I tought of converting the DFB['original'] into list and then use regex, but this way I wont get the matching result from column 'my'.

Comment: You should provide your data for copy paste, not as image, so it is very hard to help you. But i think you should have a look at DataFrame.merge() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: I am sorry for the images. As of merge() - I can not join the columns, because item column in DFA contains more words than in the DFB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe not the best solution, but it seems to be working.
I did cartesian join and then check the records which contains the data needed

```
dfa['join'] = 1
dfb['join'] = 1
dfFull = dfa.merge(dfb, on='join').drop('join' , axis=1)
dfFull['match'] = dfFull.apply(lambda x: x.original in x.item, axis = 1)
dfFull[dfFull['match']]
```